# Center align sub nav menu dependent on its width against its parent width

Tags: css, menu, navigation, center

I have been working on a bootstrap menu that I want to customise to look like the image attached here:

[image: screenshot nav]

I have been able to get the initial 'GB' hover sub nav working quite close at http://www.bubbleweb.eu/ewp-nav2/nav.php which works well. The problem I am having is with the dropdown below 'ENGLAND', which isn't aligning correct because I have forced the sub nav to align below the 'GB' menu using the following:

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
     left: -120%;
 }
```

Does anybody have any advice to control this via css to align the sub nav below the parent dependent on the width of the parent nav?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Jamie, please take a tour of the help center and see how to ask a good question.  You have asked four questions (one of which is a duplicate of another - which you also shouldn't do - you should have edited the first question) and none of these questions are in the correct format to be answered properly on this site.  If you continue as you are, you will most likely be downvoted on numerous questions and then be blocked from asking further questions

Comment: Hi Pete, cheers for your reply. Apologies if it's not written correctly but I'm not sure I follow in regards to that being four questions? Cheers

Comment: You will get a lot more attention on this issue if you heed the advice of @Paulie_D. Include the relevant code here in the question and even better, a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your issue.